# Browser Plugin Tabs - how to show one and hide the other?

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a prototype browser plugin which opens a popup window, I want to display the main page but have the option to switch to another tab to alter preferences. Currently I can only get it to display the forms for both tabs or display nothing, depending on where I put the 'display:none' part. Here is my code, which currently shows all the options and clicking tab buttons does nothing, any help appreciated.

```
<header class="panel-section panel-section-header">
    <div class="icon-section-header"><!-- An image goes here. --></div>
    <div class="text-section-header">Privacy Tool Header</div>
</header>

<div class="panel-section panel-section-tabs">
    <button class="panel-section-tabs-button selected" onclick="showHide(Home)">Home</button>
    <button class="panel-section-tabs-button" onclick="showHide('Preferences')">Preferences</button>
</div>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="panel-section panel-section-formElements">
        <div class="panel-formElements-item">
            <label for="content">What would you like to post?</label>
            <select id="content">
                <option value="default" selected="true"></option>
                <option value="text">Text</option>
                <option value="image">Image</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-formElements-item">
            <label for="network">Where would you like to post it?</label>
            <select id="network">
                <option value="default" selected="true"></option>
                <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
                <option value="twitter">Twitter</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Preferences" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="panel-section panel-section-formElements">
        <div class="panel-formElements-item">
            <label for="location">Share your location?</label>
            <select id="location">
                <option value="default" selected="true"></option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-formElements-item">
            <label for="self">Share photos of yourself?</label>
            <select id="self">
                <option value="default" selected="true"></option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="options.js"></script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(tab) {
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent')
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementById(tab.id.replace(/(\d)/g, '-1$')).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<footer class="panel-section panel-section-footer">
    <button class="panel-section-footer-button">Cancel</button>
    <div class="panel-section-footer-separator"></div>
    <button class="panel-section-footer-button default">Go</button>
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @reluctantluddite.
Did you have a chance to check out my answer, does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I just developed to make switching tabs easy.

The function `showPanelTab()` will accept either a number or a string. The number must be the number of the tab to display (0-indexed) or if passing a string it must be the tab element id.

**The included CSS is NOT required**, it is only to illustrate the end result. If you're using this code in a Firefox or Chrome Extension then the browser will take care of styling the HTML.

```js
'use strict';
const panel_tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
const panel_tab_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-section-tabs-button");

function showPanelTab(tab_id) {
  if (typeof(tab_id) == 'number') tab_id = panel_tabs[tab_id].id;
  hidePanelTabs();
  if (!tab_id) return;
  document.getElementById(tab_id).style.display = '';
  Array.from(panel_tab_buttons).forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.getAttribute('data-tab') == tab_id) element.classList.add('selected');
    else element.classList.remove('selected');
  });
}

function showPanelTabClick(e) {
  var tab_id = e.target.getAttribute('data-tab');
  showPanelTab(tab_id);
}

function hidePanelTabs() {
  Array.from(panel_tabs).forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
Array.from(panel_tab_buttons).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', showPanelTabClick);
});
hidePanelTabs(); // Hide all the tab contents
showPanelTab('tab_one'); // Display the tab with the id 'tab_one'
showPanelTab(0); // Display the Nth tab, in this case the same as 'tab_one'
```

```css
.text-section-header {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 15pt
}

div.panel-section {
  clear: both;
  margin: 5px
}

button.panel-section-tabs-button {
  float: left
}

button.panel-section-tabs-button.selected {
  color: blue
}

div.tabcontent {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-section panel-section-header">
      <div class="text-section-header" id="header-title">Test of tabs</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-section panel-section-tabs">
      <button class="panel-section-tabs-button" data-tab="tab_one">Tab 1</button>
      <div class="panel-section-tabs-separator"></div>
      <button class="panel-section-tabs-button" data-tab="tab_two">Tab 2</button>
      <div class="panel-section-tabs-separator"></div>
      <button class="panel-section-tabs-button" data-tab="tab_settings">Settings</button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-section tabcontent" id="tab_one">
      <p>This is tab_one</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-section tabcontent" id="tab_two">
      <p>This is tab_two</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum in nec purus commodo, placerat nisl fringilla, faucibus nisl. Integer tempor euismod orci nec tristique. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-section tabcontent" id="tab_settings">
      <p>This is tab_settings</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum proin posuere, lectus at porttitor lacinia, orci lacus porttitor sem, ac pretium libero mauris tristique nisl. Suspendisse a sapien at tellus posuere dignissim.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="tabs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```